# Quero declarar uma variável javascript pelo INPUT TEXT

Tags: javascript, ajax

Gostaria de fazer o inverso desse script, nesse script vc clica no botão GERAR, ele gera 4 digitos

Oque eu quero fazer é o inverso, eu quero declarar a variavel "1298105"(ou qualquer outra) e clicar em Gerar e ele gerar abaixo em uma `<div>` o resultado "1298105XXXX" conforme declarado no `input`

Como fazer, algum exemplo ?

```js
            function gerar() {

                // numero aleatorios
                var numeros = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    var sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

                    if (sorteio == 0)
                        sorteio = 1; // 1 - 9

                    numeros[i] = sorteio; 
                }

                var senha = numeros.join('');

                document.getElementById('txtsenha').value = senha;
            }
```

```html
        <input type="text" name="txtsenha" id="txtsenha"/>
        <input type="button" value="Gerar" onclick="javascript:gerar()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function gerar() {
                // numero aleatorios
                var numeros = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    var sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);

                    if (sorteio == 0)
                        sorteio = 1; // 1 - 9

                    numeros[i] = sorteio; 
                }

                var senha = numeros.join('');


    var x = document.getElementById("txtsenha").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+senha;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtsenha" id="txtsenha"/>
<input type="button" value="Gerar" onclick="javascript:gerar()"/>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo Leo, Obrigado pela resposta , dê uma olhada no meu perfil, estou tendo outro problema com javas ( ja procurei solução no google e nao encontrei ), se puder me mostra o caminho fico grato.